# how to import user defined packages in java program?

Tags: java

```
some.java
import A.A1.*;

Directory structure
  A
  |_A2
  |  |_some.java
  |_A1
     |_someother files and java files
```

but import statement didn't work. What is the reason?

Comment: from the code given it should work , can you please provide more info

Comment: Can you be more specific in saying how the import statement didn't work? I.e. what error message did you get, or what else is making you feel it doesn't work?

Comment: Its not clear from the question what you want to import.. the directory structure looks fine, can you tell what error message you are getting

Comment: The `CLASSPATH` should point to the parent dir of `A`.

Comment: Note that using import with * is usually a bad idea. Import only classes you really need.

Answer (score 1):

I hope `A` is not your current directory.

Perhaps you already know that packages work with directory heirarchies.

```
<curr-dir>
 |-A
 | |-A1
 | | |- Class1.class
 | | `- Class2.class
 | `-A2
 |   |-Class3.class
 |   `-Class4.class
 `-<other dirs>
```

Now if `<curr-dir>` is in your classpath then `import A.A1.*` will import Class1 and Class2.

Hope that is detailed enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Any class in a given package must have a package statement, and must be declared public (in most cases) to be read outside the package:

```
package A.A1;
public class ClassName{}
```

Answer (score 0):

package A.A1;

import A.A2.*;

public class ex2{}

Answer (score 0):

Dude *(star operator) does not work for user created packages!
you need to import each class individually..